# Can't fully migrate my ASP.NET core app from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: c#, cookies, https

I've been developing a webpage for some months now with Visual Studio, and recently wanted to add a cookie in the form of a GUID to assosiate each user with their requests. Unfortunately, when I try to do this, Chrome throws the following error:
[image: chrome error]
So I tried to read up on how to migrate from HTTP to HTTPS, but no matter what I do, the cookie seems to always be in danger of going "across" different security levels, and therefore not sent. I've done all sorts of setup, but no dice.
I've confirmed that I have a trusted SSL certificate (provided automatically by Visual Studio, if I understand correctly):

[[image: .net cli trust commands]]

I've configured my program.cs to do all manner of things like setting up Hsts and HTTPS redirect, as well as cookie configuration:

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using System.Net;
using VisualAIzer.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SDJsonService>();
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("example.com");
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.example.com");
});
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax,
};

app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I've configured my appsettings.json with http and https urls:

```html
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
        // No certificate configuration needed for development
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I've set up my cookie to be both secure AND have samesite policy set to none in the Index() method:

```html
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["userGuid"] == null)        // checking if the user's session already has a `GUID` cookie
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();       // create a new GUID if there is none
        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions       // cookie behavior
        {
            Secure = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            HttpOnly = true,                                // makes cookie more secure (for some reason)
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30)
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("userGuid", guid, cookieOptions);   // appends the cookie to the response, that is sent to the user's browser that receives the cookie and saves it for future use.
    }
    return View();
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I'm not at all familiar with this HTTPS business... I hope I'm doing something obvious. Are there straightforward steps to take in order to migrate a development app fully form HTTP to HTTPS? Thanks!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdpV.png)

Comment: Please don´t share only images of code. Add the code as formatted text to the question.